# Compute integral using Residue theorem, not by manipulating the denominator

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need to compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}dx$$

using the residue theorem. I know I can manipulate this to

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}dx$$

Then make a u sub and BAM its arctan of $x+1$, but how to do using the residue rules from Gamelin and Green's text on complex analysis I am stumped. I found the roots of the denominator as

$$-1 \pm i$$

Since I have a top function and bottom function, is the residue the top over the derivative of the bottom with the points plugged in ? If this is a duplicate, sorry in advance just point me to the page where its been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to choose the path $\Gamma_R=\gamma_R\cup[-R,R]$. That's it the superior semicircle or radius $R>\sqrt2$.
So taking $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}$ we have that
$$\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz=\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz+\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz$$
By the residues theorem
$$\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz=2\pi iRes(f,-1+i)=2\pi i\frac{1}{2z+2}_{z=-1+i}=\frac{2\pi i}{-2+2i+2}=\frac{2\pi i}{2i}=\pi$$
because the only root that is inside the contour is $-1+i$.
Now note that
$$|\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz|\leq\int_{0}^{\pi}|\frac{Re^{it}}{R^2e^{2it}+2Re^{it}+2}dt|\leq\pi\frac{R}{R^2-2R-2}\to 0$$ as $R\to \infty$.
So
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz=0+\pi=\pi$$

Comment: So, here your $\Gamma_R$ is the upper half circle, correct? As $-1+i \in \Gamma_R$

Comment: Yes! You can also compute taking de other half circle and the other pole and the result must be the same. Note that $-1+i\in int(\Gamma_R) $

Comment: Aha, thanks so much!